# how to apply infinite loading on jquery footable implemented html table

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll, footable

I want to use infinite loading on jquery footable implemented html table, instead of using it's pagination feature.

I tried implementing some scroll, infinite loading plugins, but it's look and functioning was changed.

so any workaround or approach to apply infinite loading on footable implemented html table.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to initialize a listener when the document is ready that triggers the loading as layed out in this snippet.

```
var win = $(window);
win.scroll(function() {
    if(win.scrollTop() + win.height() >= $(document).height()) {
        loadMoreItems();
    }
});
```

Second you need a function that retrieves more items and appends them to the table as layed out in this snippet.

```
function loadMoreItems() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/your/ajax/url/",
        success: function(response) {
            var footable = $('#yourTableId').data('footable');
            for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                footable.appendRow(response[i]);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

In this example your response has to be a JSON encoded array of HTML-strings, each being a table row (`<tr>...</tr>`). This example simply combines [jQuery's AJAX capabilities](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and [Footable](http://fooplugins.com/footable/demos/add-delete-row.htm).

Hope it helps! :)